# Two files with apparently the same codecs, but one doesn't work on my TV

Tags: video-conversion, codec, video-encoding, video-codecs

So, I have these two files. File 1 works perfectly on my TV, but file 2 doesn't (TV says file format not supported). But checking the MediaInfo, it appears that the codecs are the same. Am I missing something? Here it goes:

File 1:

```
Video
ID                             : 1
Format                         : HEVC
Format/Info                    : High Efficiency Video Coding
Format profile                 : Main 10@L5@Main
Codec ID                       : V_MPEGH/ISO/HEVC
Duration                       : 23 min 20 s
Bit rate                       : 1 063 kb/s
Width                          : 1 920 pixels
Height                         : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio           : 16:9
Frame rate mode                : Constant
Frame rate                     : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
Color space                    : YUV
Chroma subsampling             : 4:2:0
Bit depth                      : 10 bits
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)             : 0.021
Stream size                    : 177 MiB (66%)
Title                          : [bonkai77]
Writing library                : x265 2.5+6-d11482e5fedb:[Windows][GCC 6.2.1][64 bit] 10bit
Encoding settings              : cpuid=1173503 / frame-threads=2 / numa-pools=4 / wpp / no-pmode / no-pme / no-psnr / no-ssim / log-level=2 / input-csp=1 / input-res=1920x1080 / interlace=0 / total-frames=33576 / level-idc=0 / high-tier=1 / uhd-bd=0 / ref=6 / no-allow-non-conformance / no-repeat-headers / annexb / no-aud / no-hrd / info / hash=0 / no-temporal-layers / open-gop / min-keyint=23 / keyint=250 / bframes=8 / b-adapt=2 / b-pyramid / bframe-bias=0 / rc-lookahead=60 / lookahead-slices=0 / scenecut=40 / no-intra-refresh / ctu=32 / min-cu-size=8 / rect / no-amp / max-tu-size=16 / tu-inter-depth=3 / tu-intra-depth=3 / limit-tu=4 / rdoq-level=2 / dynamic-rd=0.00 / no-ssim-rd / signhide / no-tskip / nr-intra=0 / nr-inter=0 / no-constrained-intra / no-strong-intra-smoothing / max-merge=4 / limit-refs=3 / limit-modes / me=3 / subme=5 / merange=57 / temporal-mvp / weightp / weightb / no-analyze-src-pics / no-deblock / no-sao / no-sao-non-deblock / rd=5 / no-early-skip / rskip / no-fast-intra / no-tskip-fast / no-cu-lossless / b-intra / rdpenalty=0 / psy-rd=0.80 / psy-rdoq=2.00 / no-rd-refine / analysis-reuse-mode=0 / no-lossless / cbqpoffs=0 / crqpoffs=0 / rc=crf / crf=22.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpstep=4 / stats-write=0 / stats-read=0 / ipratio=1.40 / pbratio=1.30 / aq-mode=2 / aq-strength=1.00 / cutree / zone-count=0 / no-strict-cbr / qg-size=32 / no-rc-grain / qpmax=69 / qpmin=0 / no-const-vbv / sar=0 / overscan=0 / videoformat=5 / range=0 / colorprim=2 / transfer=2 / colormatrix=2 / chromaloc=0 / display-window=0 / max-cll=0,0 / min-luma=0 / max-luma=1023 / log2-max-poc-lsb=8 / vui-timing-info / vui-hrd-info / slices=1 / opt-qp-pps / opt-ref-list-length-pps / no-multi-pass-opt-rps / scenecut-bias=0.05 / no-opt-cu-delta-qp / no-aq-motion / no-hdr / no-hdr-opt / no-dhdr10-opt / analysis-reuse-level=5 / scale-factor=0 / refine-intra=0 / refine-inter=0 / refine-mv=0 / no-limit-sao / ctu-info=0
Default                        : Yes
Forced                         : No

Audio #1
ID                             : 2
Format                         : AAC LC
Format/Info                    : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                       : A_AAC-2
Duration                       : 23 min 21 s
Bit rate                       : 265 kb/s
Channel(s)                     : 6 channels
Channel layout                 : C L R Ls Rs LFE
Sampling rate                  : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                     : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode               : Lossy
Delay relative to video        : 9 ms
Stream size                    : 44.5 MiB (17%)
Language                       : English
Default                        : Yes
Forced                         : No

Audio #2
ID                             : 3
Format                         : AAC LC
Format/Info                    : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                       : A_AAC-2
Duration                       : 23 min 21 s
Bit rate                       : 265 kb/s
Channel(s)                     : 6 channels
Channel layout                 : C L R Ls Rs LFE
Sampling rate                  : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                     : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode               : Lossy
Delay relative to video        : 9 ms
Stream size                    : 44.7 MiB (17%)
Language                       : Japanese
Default                        : No
Forced                         : No
```

File 02:

```
>Video
ID                             : 1
Format                         : HEVC
Format/Info                    : High Efficiency Video Coding
Format profile                 : Main@L5@Main
Codec ID                       : V_MPEGH/ISO/HEVC
Duration                       : 24 min 41 s
Bit rate                       : 966 kb/s
Width                          : 1 920 pixels
Height                         : 1 072 pixels
Display aspect ratio           : 16:9
Frame rate mode                : Constant
Frame rate                     : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
Color space                    : YUV
Chroma subsampling             : 4:2:0
Bit depth                      : 8 bits
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)             : 0.020
Stream size                    : 171 MiB (82%)
Default                        : Yes
Forced                         : No

Audio #1
ID                             : 2
Format                         : AAC LC
Format/Info                    : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                       : A_AAC-2
Duration                       : 24 min 41 s
Bit rate                       : 99.4 kb/s
Channel(s)                     : 2 channels
Channel layout                 : L R
Sampling rate                  : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                     : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode               : Lossy
Delay relative to video        : 20 ms
Stream size                    : 17.5 MiB (8%)
Title                          : English Stereo
Language                       : English
Default                        : Yes
Forced                         : No

Audio #2
ID                             : 3
Format                         : AAC LC
Format/Info                    : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                       : A_AAC-2
Duration                       : 24 min 41 s
Bit rate                       : 96.0 kb/s
Channel(s)                     : 2 channels
Channel layout                 : L R
Sampling rate                  : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                     : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode               : Lossy
Delay relative to video        : 20 ms
Stream size                    : 16.8 MiB (8%)
Title                          : Japanese Stereo
Language                       : Japanese
Default                        : No
Forced                         : No
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the codec, but codec settings when encoded that are not supported.

Best I can tell the format is not supported (line 2) 2nd file is HEVC format.

Comment: First file is 10bit video, while the second is the more normal 8bit. Also slightly odd height for the second, 1072 instead of 1080.